# Is it possible to set up material-ui AppBar/ToolBar to have a horizontal tab menu layout?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Looking for the way to create a horizontal navigation menu for the web application using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) components. I'd like to start with something very similar to the menu at the react documentation website:

[image: react documentation menu]

Since it's a quite common menu look, I was searching for the example of such configuration but was unable to found it either at material-ui docs or here at SO (there is a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005883/4279419), but it is not exactly what's needed).

How to do this?

Comment: I believe that was made with React Bootstrap, not material-ui. Note that the React Bootstrap docs use the same nav menu:  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution for this was to place a ToolbarGroup component within AppBar's iconElementRight property.

```
// Defining a stateless, functional component, MyNavLinks. 
// This component contains your navigation links.

const MyNavLinks = () => (
  <ToolbarGroup>
    <FlatButton label="Dashboard" containerElement={<Link to="dashboard"/>}/>
    <FlatButton label="Settings" containerElement={<Link to="settings" />}/>
    <FlatButton label="Profile" containerElement={<Link to="profile" />}/>
  </ToolbarGroup> 
);


// Another stateless, functional component, MyAppBar. 
// Here we are setting the iconElementRight property of Material UI's AppBar 
// to the component defined above.

const MyAppbar = () => (
    <AppBar
      title="Brand"
      iconElementRight={<MyNavLinks />}
    />
);
```

Result:
[image: Sample Result]

Comment: Please do put commentary on your answer so that it can be more helpful.

Comment: How did you change the style of the toolbar to be transparent and how did you vertically center the toolbar?

Comment: Yea so hard for me googling about it, so many depracted including flatbutton

Comment: This answer saved my life.